# Porting custom media player app to Linux

Tags: qt

I have developed a custom media player that works on Windows 7. I used [QMediaPlayer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html), [QVideoWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvideowidget.html) and [QMediaPlaylist](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmediaplaylist.html) classes. I need to port the app to Linux. Do these classes also exist for Linux? Do they come automatically when installing Qt?

I tried copying the project to my Linux partition and recompiling but it can not find the headers.

Comment: I don't see a reason why the classes should not be available on Linux. Can you add the compilation errors please?

Comment: Have you used the same `.pro` file across the two platforms?

Comment: @cmannett85  Yes I did.

Comment: @ Simon Warta, it is complaining it can not include QtMultimedia/QMediaPlaylist.

Comment: What version of Qt are you using on the Linux machine?

Comment: @nnb That was it.  I had an older version on the Linux side of my machine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check weather the major version of Qt is the same on both platforms.

Seeing your description, I believe you are using an older version of Qt on the Linux machine as compared to the Windows machine.

Hope this helps.